# puppet-5 hiera not working

Tags: puppet, hiera

I recently upgraded puppet version 3 to version 5. all is working fine with the new version but hiera configurations for puppet 5 is not working as expected. I think I missing something which would deploy changes in the remote node. Please advise what should I do here. below are the configurations for my setup.

1) Hiera.yaml

## cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/hiera.yaml

version: 5
hierarchy:
  - name: "Master"
    path: "environments/%{environment}/data/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
    data_hash: yaml_data
    datadir: /etc/puppetlabs/code/

2) And my Environment YAML files are kept at

## cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/data/puppetsr7.demo.com.yaml

demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit: '64'

3) but when I run the command on my remote node, nothing is changing

## /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent

4) In order to troubleshoot I tried to run the command

## puppet lookup --explain demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit --environment staging --node puppetsr7.demo.com

and got below output

```
Searching for "lookup_options"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/hiera.yaml"
    Hierarchy entry "Master"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/data/puppetsr7.demo.com.yaml"
        Original path: "environments/%{environment}/data/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
        Found key: "lookup_options" value: nil
  Module data provider for module "demo" not found
Searching for "demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/hiera.yaml"
    Hierarchy entry "Master"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/data/puppetsr7.demo.com.yaml"
        Original path: "environments/%{environment}/data/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
        Found key: "demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit" value: "64"
```

It's showing the proper value when running from CLI i.e 64 which I need to be get applied on a remote node in php.ini and change the value from 512 to 64.

But don't know how to proceed further from here as I struck now. please help to troubleshoot this.

Comment: would be helpful if anyone point me to the correct directions !

Answer (score 1):

What I did is I kept the required class in site.pp file as well which I want to get executed through hieradata.
"**`demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit: '64'`**" in **hiera file** and "**`demo::configuration::phpini::memory_limit`** in **site.pp**.
Hoping that some one could get help from it.